# Problemas em atualizar a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3, realmdb

Estou com dificuldades em conseguir dar `reloadData()` na UICollectionView quando utilizo o `UISearchBar`. Debugando para ver se o objeto vindo do REALM estava `nil` percebi que a função para filtrar esta vindo com os valores correto. Pórem ao dar `reloadData()` na collection nada acontece....

Classe da UICollectionView

```
 class HomeViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchBarDelegate {

//MARK: - IBOutlet
@IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var ListOfMovies: UICollectionView!

//MARK: - Variables
var movies : Results<Moviess>!

var indexPath: IndexPath!
let realm = try! Realm()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ListOfMovies.delegate = self
    ListOfMovies.dataSource = self
    searchbar.delegate = self
    getRequest()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getObjects()
}
func getObjects() -> Results<Moviess>{
    movies = realm.objects(Moviess.self)
    return movies
}

func getRequest(){
    if getObjects().count < 1 {
        RequestData.requisicao { (result) in
               switch(result){
                case .success(let detalhe):
                    self.ListOfMovies.reloadData()
                    print(detalhe)
                case .failure(let error):
                   print(error)
               }
           }
    }}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print( getObjects().count,"<---  Items")
    return getObjects().count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "listOfMovies", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

    let infos = getObjects()[indexPath.item]
    cell.configurationMovie(movie: infos)
    return cell
  }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let infos = getObjects()[indexPath.item]
    infos.togleFavorite()
    ListOfMovies.reloadData()
    print(infos.title)
}


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width/2-20, height: 200) : CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width/3-20, height: 250)
  }

  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print(searchText)
    if !searchText.isEmpty{

        movies = getObjects().filter("title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText)
        print(movies.count, "<----- item FIltred")
        self.ListOfMovies.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}

Quando eu digito algo no searchbar me aparece isso

```
20 <---  Items
 A
10 <----- item FIltred. <-- Aqui é onde ele filtra o resultados
20 <---  Items <--- Apos o reloadData() da collection ele volta com os itens iniciais
```

Classe do objeto REALM

```
import RealmSwift
import UIKit

class Moviess: Object{
 @objc dynamic var id = 0
 @objc dynamic var title = ""
 @objc dynamic var overview = ""
 @objc dynamic var poster = ""
 @objc dynamic var isFavorites = false

 override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
 }
 convenience init (id: Int){
    self.init()
    self.id = id
 }

 override class func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["isFavorites"]
 }

 func insertMovieData(list: Moviess){
    do {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write({ () -> Void in
            realm.add(list)
        })
    } catch let error as NSError{
        print("insert error : \(error)")
    }
 }

 func togleFavorite(){
    try? realm?.write{
        isFavorites = !isFavorites
    }
  }
}
```

Onde Posso estar errando?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro da função `numberOfItemsInSection` você está chamando `getObjects()`, ela está "resetando" os valores de `movies` para todos os objetos que você tem no Realm:

```
func getObjects() -> Results<Moviess>{
    movies = realm.objects(Moviess.self)
    return movies
}
```

E a sua tabela é preenchida com essa variável. Quando você chama o `reloadData()`, uma das funções executadas do dataSource da tableView é o `numberOfItemsInSection`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print( getObjects().count,"<---  Items")
    return getObjects().count
  }
```

Basicamente você está filtrando os dados, e, quando vai atualizar a tabela, está fazendo fetch de todos os dados novamente.